# Parenthesis around operator symbol in type signature

Tags: haskell, syntax, operators, special-characters, type-signature

```
. :: (a -> b) -> (c -> a) -> c -> b
f . g = \ x -> f (g x)
```

Why is this definition illegal? Aesthetic choice, or formal necessity?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's for consistency. Infix operators by themselves aren't *expressions* whose type or value you could define. The following is also not legal:

```
. = \f g x -> f (g x)
```

...though that is basically what your definition is desugared to. But for directly *defining the value of an infix* this way, we need to first disable the special syntactic status, and that's done by wrapping it in parentheses:

```
(.) :: (a -> b) -> (c -> a) -> c -> b
(.) = \f g x -> f (g x)
```

This is quite the same as defining

```
compose :: (a -> b) -> (c -> a) -> c -> b
compose = \f g x -> f (g x)
```

...which can then also be used as an infix, like

```
Prelude> map (toEnum `compose` round) $ [110 + sin x * 12 | x<-[0..30]] :: String
"nxypebkvzsgbhszvkbepyxndclwyqfb"
```

But you obviously wouldn't write the definition in infix form, like

```
`compose` :: (a -> b) -> (c -> a) -> c -> b
`compose` = \f g x -> f (g x)
```

...though you could do

```
f`compose`g = \x -> f (g x)
```

Comment: I can absolutely follow that logic. But wouldn't a combination of backtick notation and symbol operator infix assumption extended to on the left-hand side of `=` suffice for formal consistency? The examples would still be legal; `((((+ 2)))) 3  ==  5`. `. g = \ f x -> f (g x)` could work just as `(. (+ 1)) (+ 2) 4` does. If symbol operators are already an exception to Haskell's regular polish notation, why not use this exception for declaration / name binding also?

Comment: @GeorgJohannSchubert Because exceptions in the syntax are bad, and are avoided (typically) at all costs. Note that the pattern and expression syntax are very similair - patterns essentially have expression syntax (plus things like ViewPatterns, etc) and the additional constraint that each variable appears at most once. Such an exception would lead to inconsistency between the pattern and expression syntax.

Comment: @user2407038 Can you elaborate? I'm not sure what you mean by "inconsistency between the pattern and expression syntax". Isn't exception to exception (excepted infix assumption for operator symbols in patterns) more incoherent than just exception (infix assumption)?

Comment: @GeorgJohannSchubert I don't think it makes much sense to talk about “excepted infix assumption for operator symbols in patterns”. The important point is just how expressions are parsed: broadly speaking, the parser tries to grab for every infix (say `%`) expressions on the left and right as arguments. If both are found, like `2%7`, it desugars this to `(%) 2 7`. Basically, the `()` in `(%)` aren't parentheses in the grouping-sense at all, they're rather symbol-quotation marks.

Comment: In `((4 +))`, you don't have "parenthesis around symbolic operators", you have: 1. normal grouping parentheses around expression `(4 +)`; 2. parentheses _in_ `(4 +)`, which also have a special meaning, but a different one than parentheses in `(+)`: you can't write e.g. `f = 4 +`, only `f = (4 +)`.

Comment: `+` is just a symbol that is treated by the parser in some way. `(+)` is the function. Your argumentation is a bit like saying: why can't we write `hello world :: String`? Surely `hello world` is a string, and you _can_ write `"hello world" :: String`. Well, yes, but those quotation marks are important for the parser to actually interpret it as a string. Likewise, you need to surround `+` with parentheses so it's actually treated as a function.

Comment: @leftaroundabout `3 + 4` isn't just perfectly regular *function* application? Because the parser says so? Maybe this is one of those things whiches compehension requires some intuition that I have not yet aquired. I can follow your answers, but can't accept that there *should* be semantic difference between `map (add 4)`'s and `(+)`'s parenthesis. Probably a case of Scheme-itis.

Comment: Nonetheless: Thank you for discussing this.

Comment: If `3 + 4` were regular function application, it would be parsed as `(((3)(+))(4))`: the function `3` applied to `+` and `4`. In Scheme it would in fact be parsed this way, thus the need to write it `(+ 3 4)` instead to make any sense. Haskell doesn't do this because we want actual infix notation, as most people would consider `3 + 4` more readable than `(+ 3 4)`.